# How do you "combine variables" in JavaScript to satisfy JSLint?

Tags: javascript, jslint

For a school project, I am trying to make a website that does stuff.
To make it, I am using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. I am using a compiler that gives debug hints. These hints are provided from **JSLint**. I am told that I should combine two of the variables that I have written, but I do not understand what this means.

I have done some research (on Stack Overflow and other websites), but all of these come up with people wanting to put variables into arrays.

Would anybody kindly explain to me what I should do?

**The code (simplified):**

```
var x = document.getElementById("some id");
var y = document.getElementById("some other id");
var z = document.getElementsByTagName("some tag name");
```

**And JSLint says:**

*"Combine this with the previous 'var' statement:   var y = document.getElementById("some other id");"*
**and:**

*Combine this with the previous 'var' statement.    var z = document.getElementsByTagName("some tag name");*

*Important Note*: The code **does** work, but JSLint is telling me to fix it.

Comment: So many upvote for research effort ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to let you know, what you wrote is valid JavaScript. The error is more about style. It matters if you are in strict mode.

What the error is saying is you need to combine all the variable declarations into one line using the comma operator to separate them.

```
var x = document.getElementById("some id"),
    y = document.getElementById("some other id"),
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("some tag name");
```

You can get JSLInt error explanations [here](https://jslinterrors.com/combine-this-with-the-previous-var-statement)

Answer (score 9):

```
var x = document.getElementById("some id"),
    y = document.getElementById("some other id"),
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("some tag name");
```

You can declare variables like in the example above.

Answer (score 9):

It's telling you to chain your variable declarations instead of listing them individually.  In js you do this with a comma to separate declarations, instead of a semi-colon to denote end of statement.

The following is 3 separate delcarations...

```
var x = document.getElementById("some id");
var y = document.getElementById("some other id");
var z = document.getElementsByTagName("some tag name");
```

To make this one declaration of 3 different variables (with their definitions)...

```
var x = document.getElementById("some id"),
    y = document.getElementById("some other id"),
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("some tag name");
```

**NOTE** This still has to end with a semi-colon to delimit the (variable declaration) statement.

Comment: Okay. I get it now. Thanks for helping! :)